# How to Draw Many Polylines in Google Map Efficiently?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am currently learning to make an android app that uses Google Map to display data to the users. Currently I am using Polyline to draw out all the "data/lines" that I want to show on the map, but I draw it straight on the Google Map, like mMap.addPolyline(...). (I wish I can post a screenshot but I don't have at least 10 reputation :-( ).

But I am having some performance issues over drawing all these lines on the map, because they consists of like 500 ~ 900 lines in a small area there (by zooming in). The issue is that when the app is drawing all these data, the app hang/stop for a second, like froze, then once it is finished drawing, the app continue to work.

So my question is, how can I draw that many Polylines smoothly without having the app to hang/stop for a second when it is drawing on the map? Such as the user can move around the map while the Polylines are being drawn on the map?

I had tried on drawing Polylines on the map in a different thread, but I got an error something like must draw on the main thread (can't remember the exact Exception error). Other than that, I also searched over the Internet for example like this, but I only found the example with Overlay or ItemizedOverlay things, but those are deprecated as far as I know. Is there any other options for doing this? Can you show me some examples or guide me to the right resources? Showing me some code would be very helpful.

Thank you

**Update:**
Forgot to include my code here, and here is the code that I draw the Polylines:

```
private class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Show a message saying this app is fetching data
        Toast.makeText(mMainActivity,
                "Fetching data ...",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // Load then read the data from a url in the background
        loadData();

        readData();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

        // draw lines here
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(locations[0].getLatitude(), locations[0].getLongitude()))
                .add(new LatLng(locations[1].getLatitude(), locations[1].getLongitude()))
                .color(Color.GREEN)
                .width(5f);

        Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        lineList.add(polyline);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use asynclass for that in and show progressdialog

```
 private class ShowPolyLine extends
                AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog pdDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                try {
        pdDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
                    pdDialog.show();
                    pdDialog.setCancelable(false);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected TicketTemplate doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    // show pollyline code
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("exception", ".........................." + e);
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                     pdDialog.dismiss();




            }

        }
```

and call it as `ShowPolyLine().execute();`

Comment: Isn't it that will still cause the app/map to stop responding for a moment while drawing all the lines?

Comment: Yes this will surely take time but it will not hang your UI and the user will get to know that some work is going on.

Answer (score 0):

run fetching data to draw on background thread and draw line only on main tread, using below code we are drawing 3000 lines

```
Set<String> routeNames=cordinatePojos.keySet();
            arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
            arrayList.addAll(routeNames);
            iterator=routeNames.iterator();
            color[0]=Color.BLUE;
            color[1]=Color.GREEN;
            color[2]=Color.RED;
            color[3]=Color.CYAN;
            conuter=0;    

Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                            latLngs = cordinatePojos.get(iterator.next());
                            sortLocations(latLngs, latLngs.get(0).latitude, latLngs.get(0).longitude);
                            Log.d("test on background======",""+latLngs.get(0)+"======"+conuter);
                            final PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                            polyLineOptions.addAll(latLngs);
                            polyLineOptions.width(15-i-i);
                            polyLineOptions.color(color[i]);
                            float[] result1 = new float[3];


                            android.location.Location.distanceBetween(latLngs.get(0).latitude,latLngs.get(0).longitude, latLngs.get(latLngs.size()-1).latitude, latLngs.get(latLngs.size()-1).longitude, result1);
                            Float distance1 = result1[0];
                            totalDistance=totalDistance+distance1;
    //                      final MarkerOptions markerOptions=new MarkerOptions().position(latLngs.get(0)).title(arrayList.get(conuter)+"==distance between this road is "+ distance1/1000 + " Km");
    //                      final MarkerOptions lastMarkerOptions=new MarkerOptions().position(latLngs.get(latLngs.size()-1)).title(arrayList.get(conuter)+"==distance between this road is "+distance1/1000+ " Km");
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            /*googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                                            googleMap.addMarker(lastMarkerOptions);*/
                                            googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
                                            if (i>2) {                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                i=0;
                                            }
                                            i++;

                                    }
                                });
                             if (conuter>3000) {
                                break;
                            }
                             conuter++;

                        }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I will give it a try when I get a chance. But just another question, so I create this new thread and execute it when I want to draw my Polylines?

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
GoogleMap mMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

List<Polyline> mPolylines = new ArrayList<Polyline>();
// Add polylines to the map and the list
mPolylines.add(mMap.addPolyline(polyOpts));
...
mPolylines.add(mMap.addPolyline(polyOpts));


mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng clickCoords) {
        for (PolylineOptions polyline : mPolylines) {
            for (LatLng polyCoords : polyline.getPoints()) {
                float[] results = new float[1];
                Location.distanceBetween(clickCoords.latitude, clickCoords.longitude,
                        polyCoords.latitude, polyCoords.longitude, results);

                if (results[0] < 100) {
                    polyline.setVisible(false);
                    Log.e(TAG, "Found @ "+clickCoords.latitude+" "+clickCoords.longitude);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have already tried the way you did it, and that's the problem I am still facing now (slow/hang/stop while drawing data on map).

Comment: I have tested it on 7 different devices, Note2, Note3, Samsung tablet, nexus, Chinese brand phone, etc. They all have the same issue, so I am sure it is not my device's problem.